# Игнор запятой в строке при импорте данных в csv

Tags: python, csv

Возникла проблема при импорте данных в csv файл. В общем, не могу сделать так, чтобы запятая в строке не раскидывала ее в разные ячейки.
К примеру: `["string one", "string two", "string, with comma"]`.
При открытии файла в exel вместо трех ячеек, заполняются четыре.
Вот код записи данных в файл:

```
csv.register_dialect('customcsv')
with open("aheku.csv", "w", encoding='cp1251', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, 'customcsv', delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='', escapechar=',')
    writer.writerows(news)
```

Насколько я понимаю, `escapechar=','` должен отвечать за игнор запятой в строке или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` - означает, что ваши выходные данные не будут обернуты в кавычки. Когда в ваших данных встретится `delimiter`, то но будет заэкранирован символом `escapechar`. escapechar - это символ экранирования. Также `;` не очень похож на стандартный разделитель. В Comma Separated Values стандартным разделителем можно считать запятую. Поэтому если вы используете нестандартный разделитель - Excel должен об этом как-то узнать.

Comment: а `delimiter` разве не должен говорить об этом exel? или есть другой какой-то параметр? почитал документацию, ничего не нашлось.

Answer (score 1):

Убрал все параметры в `writer = csv.writer(f)` и проблема решилась.